# yuidoc: how to document a plugin

Tags: javascript, yuidoc

I have a javascript class which has plugins. These plugins actually add/replace functions of this class. However, I don't see how I should document these plugins. For example, if I have a class and plugin as follows

CLASS:

```
/** Foo is a .....
    @class Foo
    @constructor
*/
function Foo() { this.add = function(){...} }
```

PLUGIN:

```
(function(Foo) {
    Foo.add = function(input){...};
    Foo.bar = function() { ... };
})(Foo);
```

So, the plugin replaces the 'add' function and adds a new 'bar' function. The problem I have is that this plugin is not a class or sublcass of Foo. Nor is it a module or submodule (I think). Any suggestion what would be best to do in this situation ?

Comment: i'd make it a `@class @static` and call it a "mixin" or "decorator"

Comment: ok, but how does that look like in yuidoc notation. The mixin should somehow be related to the class Foo (and there isn't such thing as @mixin)